# Android pause event terminates the application on nexus 5 (KitKat 4.4.4)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm developing an android hybrid application using phonegap. I test my app on Galaxy S3 (JellyBean) and on Nexus 5 (KiKat 4.4.4). 
Up until few days ago the i didn't have any issues on both devices.
HOWEVER, in the past few days i'm facing an annoying issue only on the Nexus 5:
when the app goes to pause state, meaning goes to the background, it terminates for some unknown reason.
If the app tries to reach the device's camera, a pause event fires and the immediately the app terminates. It happens too when i'm pushing the home button: the app triggers the pause event, but immediately after that - it terminates :-(

Why is that ?

EDIT: COPY/PASTE from logcat

```
+12-17 15:41:53.102: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): Expected commute to have traffic statusdum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): dup <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):   du_m <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     du_x <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     du_y <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     dva: 1418823272
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     dvc <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):     dvd: 1418823687
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):   >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):   du_n <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):   >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):   duv <
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073):   >
+12-17 15:41:53.582: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): Expected commute to have traffic statusdum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dum <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): dup <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):   du_m <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     du_x <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     du_y <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     dva: 1418823272
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     dvc <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):     dvd: 1418823687
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):   >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):   du_n <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):   >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):   duv <
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073):   >
+12-17 15:41:53.652: E/TravelReport(1073): >
+12-17 15:41:59.142: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:42:19.322: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:42:28.672: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:02.752: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:03.862: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): TM Id 'battery_LCD_monitor' Sensor 'batt_therm' - alarm cleared 5 at 350.0 degC
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): TM Id 'battery_LCD_monitor' Sensor 'batt_therm' - alarm cleared 4 at 350.0 degC
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): override action 5000
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg override 5000
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): override_notify : SS mode 1 override 5000
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor3 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor3 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor8 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor8 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor7 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone7/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor7 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone7/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor6 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone6/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor6 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone6/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor5 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone5/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:43:08.932: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor5 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone5/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:43:18.122: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:20.222: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:21.292: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:24.422: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:39.502: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:49.102: E/ThermalEngine(195): TM Id 'SKIN_THERMAL_management_1' Sensor 'xo_therm_pu2' - alarm cleared 1 at 38.0 degC
+12-17 15:43:49.102: E/ThermalEngine(195): ACTION: LCD - Setting max LCD brightness to 255
+12-17 15:43:51.982: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:53.102: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:43:59.162: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:00.282: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:06.332: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:08.442: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:10.532: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:11.642: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:19.692: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:20.852: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:23.982: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:37.092: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): TM Id 'battery_LCD_monitor' Sensor 'batt_therm' - alarm cleared 3 at 340.0 degC
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): override action 7500
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg override 7500
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): override_notify : SS mode 1 override 7500
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor3 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor3 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone3/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor8 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor8 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor7 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone7/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor7 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone7/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor6 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone6/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor6 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone6/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor5 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone5/trip_point_0_type)
+12-17 15:44:38.982: E/ThermalEngine(195): enable_threshold: tsens_tz_sensor5 (/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone5/trip_point_1_type)
+12-17 15:44:39.192: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:44.292: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
+12-17 15:44:46.402: E/qcom_sensors_hal(748): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

Comment: Added logcat for @shkschneider

Comment: Ok, Houston: we got a `dum <` problem... I don't have a clue, sorry.

Comment: found the culprit!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! go to Settings -> Developer Options, under APPS section: "Don't keep activities" was enabled. I must have mistakenly enabled it. silly me.

Comment: Post that as an answer to your own question and mark it a answered so others might find the solution too.